# Why is the word for I know in Spanish "yo sé" and not "yo sabo"?

Tags: comparative-linguistics

When I was learning Spanish last year (I didn't feel forced), I found a peculiar irregularity: the word for I know. It was yo sé, which made no sense to me. I want to know why it is yo sé and not yo sabo. Is there a Latin root?

My comparative research suggest that there is a connection because I saw the words sé/saiz,sei,so in different languages ranging from Galician to Italian. So, the root is *s- in my mind, and based off the latin word sapio/sapere.

Comment: There is no particular reason I know of -- after all, nobody was keeping records at the time. But whatever the reasons, the change must have happened early if it's shared with a lot of daughter languages. One possibility is that first person verbs -- especially if they get used as qualifiers -- are used a lot more, and this tends to get their edges rubbed off. Look at _ain't_, which started off as a contraction for _am not_. Oh, and it's normal for generalizations to have exceptions; irregularity is part of the system.

Comment: @NumberFile I don't know the answer, but https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/hisverb.htm suggests it was created by analogy to "yo hé" in the verb *haber*. To me, though, that begs the question of how *habeo* turned into *hé* in the first place... but maybe that is better known, or it is also explained there and I missed it. Personally, anyway, I don't agree that "nobody was keeping records at the time" is reason enough to brush the question off; isn't comparative linguistics partly about figuring out things that we have scant records of?

Answer (score 3):

A greater range of data points might allow a better comparison of the particular way the Latin verb *sapio*, *sapere*, a regular third conjugation *-iō* verb, ended up irregular in the Romance languages.

Compare the third person singular forms, corresponding to Latin *sapit*:

> Italian: *sa* /sa/
>
> Romansh (Grischun): *sa* /sa/
>
> French: *sait* /sɛ/
>
> Occitan: *sap* /sap/
>
> Catalan: *sap* /sap/
>
> Spanish: *sabe* /ˈsa.βe/
>
> Portuguese: *sabe* /ˈsa.βɨ/ (PT), /ˈsa.bi/ (BR)
>
> Galician: *sabe* /ˈsa.be/

We see a clear distinction, in that Occitano-Catalan and Iberian Romance kept the labial consonant /p/ in some form, whether at the end of the syllable, as /p/ or voiced to /b/ and then lenited to /β/. French, Italian and Rhaeto-Romance [have not](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/how-did-sapere-lose-the-middle-consonant-p-in-its-indicative-present-table).

Contrast that with the loss of /p/ from Latin *sapiō* in the *first* person singular across all the Romance languages.

Hence, further explanation for the first person singular form is necessary. The most commonly accepted explanation for Spanish [is presented below](http://dictionnairefrancaisespagnol.net/Etude-linguistique-de-l-espagnol.pdf):

> La forme très réduite, *sé*, issue du Latin SAPIO, s'explique par sa position souvent proclitique dans le discours et par analogie avec la forme *he* de *haber*.

The combination of often being before an infinitive [specifically first person singular] and analogy with *he* from *haber* is cited.